# self-defined conneted network using tesnsorflow take too much storage and failed to train

Tags: tensorflow, training-data, decoder, belief-propagation

For my project i write a not-fully connected feedforword network using tensorflow.

I only use scalar variables to generate weights, rather than matrix variables, because of not-fully connectivity.

For this reason i get the flexibility to connet neurons from two neighouring layers respectively.

Unfortunately the training of this network take too much storages.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tTm4.png)
Also the training failed,if the network has more layers (i have an iteration to define the number of layers)

I have released my code on github: https://github.com/hezhouyuanren/BP-like-Decoder.git
.
I'm hopping for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a single scalar value for each weight, which will probably result in a huge graph structure, you can make regular fully-connected layers and *then* remove the connections that you don't need. For example, for an input *X* with *N* features and a layer of size *M*, you would have a typical weight matrix *W* of size *N* x *M*. You can then have another matrix *C*, also *N* x *M* such that C<sub>*ij*</sub> is 1 if there is a connection between input feture *i* and layer neuron *j* and 0 if there is not. The output of the layer (before activation) would then be *X* * (*W* · *C*), where * is the usual matrix product and · is the element-wise product. This should also play well with the training (assuming *C* is not trainable), since values where *C* is 0 will just not take affect the parameter updates. The only issue is that you are using a bigger matrix than you need, but unless you have very large number of very big layers, it shouldn't be much of a problem (surely less problematic than having thousands of scalar graph nodes).

Comment: @Bin I'm glad to know :) Please consider marking the answer as accepted if you think it solved your problem.